# How to set switch/case/break formatting in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, formatting

I want on `ctrl-k-f` to get next formating:

```
switch {
    case {
        // body ...
    } break;
}
```

instead of ugly:

```
switch {
case {
    // body ...
     } break;
}
```

So how to set switch/case/break formatting in visual studio 2012?

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since this isn't a C++ question.

Comment: It is a question about C++  development in Visual-Studio. Not general VS question.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't answer how to do this in VS2012 I think you can accomplish what you want with the [AStyle extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2f3f04cd-2866-4e47-a671-d1cc9cc3fb02) which is based on [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/). I've used it with VS2010 to do pretty much the same thing as you want.